# What is the drop control on Instagram?

Tags: instagram

There's a control that looks like a drop of water. What does it do?

Comment: You may want to provide a screenshot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the blur tool. You can apply linear or radial blur with this tool.

[image: Instagram blur/tear drop/tilt-shift tool]

(More details in the [Instagram Help Center](http://help.instagram.com/113650522126501))

This tool is mostly used to [simulate **tilt-shift** effect](http://mashable.com/2012/11/29/instagram-tilt-shift-tips/) (used by photographers to highlight a plane or exaggerate a minimal depth-of-field).